# C# Source Generator using SqlClient results in "Microsoft.Data.SqlClient is not supported on this platform"

Tags: c#, code-generation

i'm trying to use Microsoft.Data.SqlClient with a source generator to get additional info for the generator. However i'm encountering the "Microsoft.Data.SqlClient is not supported on this platform" error. I tried changing from "Any CPU" to "x64" but that doesn't seem to have done anything.

The generator project is on netstandard2.0 and the other is on net6.0.

Does anyone have an idea on why i'm getting this error?

Comment: We would need more details here to be able to assist you.

Comment: Sure, but what kind of details do you need? Source generation is new for me and i don't know what might be important.

Comment: See if following helps.  There are lots of good suggestions : https://github.com/dotnet/SqlClient/issues/1643

Comment: [FAQ item 11](https://github.com/dotnet/SqlClient/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions)